# Export data from table to file executes with huge time delay Using PRESTO

Tags: presto

In a recent I started using Presto DB, we were trying to export data from a table to a NFS mount partition using presto client. For an instance, table has 46Million rows and when we export data the size is 4.5G. It got executed in 15 Mins. This is a very small table in my day to day transactions. My worst case is, table will have 450Million rows and i want it to be exported efficiently. Expecting it to be completed in 15-20 mins. I could able to fetch using Impala. But my requirement is on Presto DB. I've attached my command line query which I'm using to pull data.

**Sample Query**

`presto --server hostname:8081 --catalog hive --schema dbname --user username --execute "select md5hash,email, decile , 'Hispanic' segment,(case when gqs in ('1','2','3') then '1' when gqs in ('4','5') and signal_match='Y' then '2' else '3' end) priority,l_postal,age_55_plus  from apt_rltp_request_raw_12141_postback_file  " --output-format TSV_HEADER | tr '\t' '|' > HispanicW1TRT`